# What is that twiggy strand in hair of some anime characters called?

Tags: terminology, oregairu

I remember there's a Japanese word for it, but I forgot.

Here's an image of Hachiman. That "twig" on his head.

[image]

Comment: "it's not a cow lick! it's my Tension Gauge!" - [Lucius](http://triuni.wikia.com/wiki/Lucius), Trinity Universe

Comment: Even if this question may have an answer, this question is more like an actual question. "What is this hairstyle called" doesn't specify anything for new visitors, neither is descriptive. They still have to peek in. I think instead of marking this duplicate, it should be considered more authentic. For example, when I searched for this question here, I never bothered to look inside the "What is this hairstyle called." No surprise in that.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Marking this as a duplicate doesn't mean that your question is bad or that the other one is better. The main purpose of marking duplicates is to avoid having the same answers in multiple places. I agree that the other title is rather vague and yours is more descriptive, which makes this question a useful duplicate for people searching. In the future we might want to edit the title of the other one to be more descriptive, but we'll still need to mark this one as a duplicate because the other one is already answered.

Comment: now that it's been marked duplicate, you can see how the question has a little box pointing to the question with all the answers. This question will probably get a lot of views, and the people looking for the answer can jump the link and get the info they want.

Comment: Oh I see. But still, it makes my question somewhat meaningless. And no, there's not too many views :3